# Can I hide values in nuget.config?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-5, webapi

I have nuget.config for dockerfile. And I wont to hide values. How can I do this?
For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="SomeLibrary" value="https://SomeLibrary.com/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
    <SomeLibrary>
        <add key="Username" value="username" /> //I mean here
        <add key="Password" value="password" /> //I mean here
    </SomeLibrary>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

How to hide values for "some library"???
Thank you so much

Comment: Who do you want to hide it from?

Comment: @Hans Kilian Because I want to push this config into my branch and I don't want that someone see and use my credentials in the future

Comment: Take a look at the `dotnet nuget add source` command. But you still need to provide the credentials from somewhere. Do you have an idea about where you'd store them? Or will you build manually and provide them manually?

Comment: Have you read through [this info](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/nuget-credentials.md#using-the-azure-artifact-credential-provider)?